# Ubuntu 12.04 installed Rhythmbox 2.97 instead of 2.98

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox

I've added [PPA Webupd8team/rhythmbox](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/rhythmbox) and doing `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install rhythmbox`. I do restart but it doesn't install the latest version (2.97 installed)

Is there any way to install the "2.98" or it doesn't supported for 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/rhythmbox?field.series_filter=precise

[image]

Rhythmbox version in that PPA is "**2.98.really.2.97**-1ubuntu6.1~precise2". I think this means package version is 2.98, but packaged software version is really 2.97.